# POST not working on second click of button with error ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I'm using ExpressJS to persist data server-side where a user can enter songs and then sort them by genre. However when a second/third song is submitted it causes a `400 BAD REQUEST` with the console spitting out the error `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT`.

In the HTML File:

```js
            $(document).ready(() => {
                $("#addSongSubmit").click(() => {
                    submitHandler();
                });

                $.get("/songs", (response, status) => {
                    let songs = response;
                    for(let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
                        $("#songList").append(`<tr><td>${songs[i][0]}</td><td>${songs[i][1]}</td></tr>`);
                    }
                });
            });
```

```js
function submitHandler() {
                let song = [$("#songTitle").val(), $("#genre").val()];
                if(song[0].length < 1 || song[1].length < 1) {
                    alert("Fields cannot be empty!");
                    return;
                }
                postData = JSON.stringify({"song": song,});
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/song",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: postData,
                    contentType:"application/json",
                    success: (res, status) => {
                        $("#songList").append(`<tr><td>${song[0]}</td><td>${song[1]}</td></tr>`);
                        $("#songTitle").val("");
                        $("#genre").val("");
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: (xhr,  _, err) => {
                        if(xhr.status == 400) {
                            alert(`${err}: song already exists!`);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Server side handling:

```js
app.post('/song', (req, res) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let newSong = req.body.song;
    if(songStore.length === 0) {
        songStore.push(newSong) 
    } else {
        for(let i = 0; i < songStore.length; i++) {
            if(songStore[i][0] === newSong[0]) {
                res.status(400).send({"error": "duplicate song"});
                return;
            } else {
                songStore.push(newSong);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(songStore);
    return res.status(201).send({});
});
```

```js
app.get('/songs', (req, res) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(200).send(songStore);
})
```

Comment: I suspect this may be due to the Content-Type declaration, since JSON data isn't being sent back, it skips right to the error block?

Comment: You code makes use of a variable `songStore` and assumes that this keeps its value between a POST and a subsequent GET request. I don't believe this can work, because your server must be able to handle requests from dozens of concurrent users. Please share the server-side code where you declare this variable.